# Changing scope value after clicking a button with api call

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I try to write a login function for a project. 
The idea is, when the user presses the login button, then the *checkLogin* function is called, which is checking the server in the background for the user.

Everything does well, except in the case where no user is found, then a error message should appear, which is controlled with a boolean value (e.g. *$scope.displayValidationMessage*) and *ng-show* directive.

I tried to use *$scope.$apply()* or *$scope.$digest()* to no avail.
I am using AngularJS version 1.7.8.

```
$scope.email = "";
$scope.pass = "";
$scope.displayErrorMessage = false;
$scope.displayValidationMessage = false;

$scope.checkLogin = function(){
        if($scope.email==""||$scope.pass==""){
            return $scope.displayValidationMessage=true;
        }
        var pdat = {
            username:$scope.email,
            password:$scope.pass
        };

        $http({
            method:'post',
            url: 'http://www.example.org',
            data:pdat
        }).then(function success(response){
            var resnum = response.data.resnum;
            if(resnum==1){ //User found
                var data = response.data.data;
                $cookies.put('token',data.token);
                $cookies.put('id',data.id);
                $location.path('/main')
            }else{//User not found
                $scope.displayErrorMessage = true;
            }
        },function error(response){
            $scope.displayErrorMessage=true;
        });


    };
```

```html
       <div class="notification is-warning" ng-show="displayValidationMessage">
           Please fill in every field in the form!
       </div>
```

How can I affect that the changed value of the boolean values will show the respective error message?

Comment: `scope.displayErrorMessage` should be used exactly like you're using `scope. displayValidationMessage`. Just add another div with ng-show targeting displayErrorMessage and you're done.

Comment: ...and you definitely don't need `$apply` or `$digest` if you use `$http`

Answer (score 0):

**1**: You don't need to set default value as `false`, all variables are `false` as default, also your `email` and `pass` are empty as string.

```
if(angular.isUndefined($scope.email)) {...}
```

**2**: Try to convert your properties as one `object`, it will helps you to have optimized codes.

```
--------------------------------------Html
<input ng-model="form.email">

<input ng-model="form.pass">
--------------------------------------Controller
scope.form = {email: "", pass: "", message: { validation: "", error: "" } }
```

**3**: you don't need to `return` in angularjs when you use `scope` and what you want is:

```
if(...) { scope.x = true; return false; }
```

**4**: `$scope.$apply()` not work when you are already use angularjs native codes, for example when you use `scope` it's already `apply()` in your angular:

```
var textInput = $(".textInput").val(); //jquery selector
$scope.textInput = textInput; // not bind until $apply
$scope.$apply(); //scope applied
```

**5**: as @briosheje said in your comments, `$scope.displayErrorMessage` not used in your `html`, you should use it as what you did to `$scope.displayValidationMessage`.

Answer (score 0):

When you are going into the error function as User is not found, you are setting `$scope.displayErrorMessage` as true.

But, in the HTML, there is only one div with variable `displayValidationMessage`.

Add another div having `ng-show="displayErrorMessage"` and inside it add the error message like this:

```
 <div class="notification is-warning" ng-show="displayErrorMessage">
     User not found!
 </div>
```